# Eclipse (project) clean disabled (Helios)

Tags: eclipse

I am using Helios Eclipse (part of an embedded hardware IDE :-( ) and the (Project) "Clean" menu item is grayed out.  The "Clean Project" (right click off the project) doesn't seem to do a clean either.  Can anyone suggest why?

Maybe related, but having added a new source file, this doesn't compile either.  Is some part of Eclipse failing to update itself as I modify my code?

Comment: What type of project. Current Eclipse doesn't even have a Clean Project option at least for Java projects.

Comment: Some suggestions: The project permissions might be read only or the project does not have a nature assigned, i.e. eclipse does not recognize the type.

Comment: Please show your `.project` file that contains the project natures (as already said, _Project > Clean..._ is only available for some project natures, but not for e.g. a general project without any nature).